# NodeJS передать роутинг выше

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Есть проект с такой структурой:

```
        |_catalog(dir) _ index.js
        |              _ method1.js
        |              _ method2.js
        |
        |_app.js
```

Мне нужно, что бы при запросе по `site.com/catalog/`
модуль app.js передавал обработку модулю `index.js`, а
`index.js` обрабатывал urlы `site.com/catalog/method1`
`site.com/catalog/method2` ну и вызывал соответствующие модули.

Пробовал вот так:

**app.js**

```js
const mainCatalog = require ("./catalog/index");

app.get('/catalog*', function (req, res) {
    mainCatalog(); 
});
```

**index.js**

```js
const method1 = require ("./catalog/method1");

function foo () {
    app.get('/catalog/method1', function (req, res) {
        method1();
    });
}

module.exports = foo;
```

Но ничего не выходит.

Comment: Делается это через [express.Router](https://expressjs.com/ru/guide/routing.html) *(в самом низу)*

Comment: У вас слеш пропущен /catalog/*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможное, вот так:
**index.js**

```js
const express = require('express');
const method1 = require ("./catalog/method1");

const router = express.Router(); // Создаем роутер

router.get('/method1', function(req, res) { // Самая обычная обработка запроса
    method1();
});

module.exports = router;
```

**app.js**

```js
// Вместо этого комментария вероятное стоит require('express')
const mainCatalog = require ("./catalog/index");

// Тут где-то инициализация app

app.use('/catalog', mainCatalog); // Теперь по запросу "/catalog/mathod1" вызывается method1()
```

Comment: Это не работает. делаю запрос http://127.0.0.1:3000//catalog/method1 бесконечно грузится, но и не отбивает с "Cannot GET". Скорее всего, дело в этой строчке app.use('/catalog', mainCatalog); она не передаёт дальше управление.

Comment: а не, всё ок, сам затупил.